# Bootstrap responsive grid with right fixed sidebar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to create a template with bootstrap like that, which respect the grid's responsive system :

[image: template]

In the picture, the navbar and the right side (which contains the two buttons) are sticky (always show on the view)

My problem is the right side because, in bootstrap grid system the right side block would be considered a single row while the main content contains multiples row. How I can do that ?

Comment: Do you want the sidebar to be part of the 12 columns (1 or 2 columns wide) or should the 12 columns be as wide as the main content (is it part of the grid or not)? _"the right side block would be considered a single row"_: eh? Did you mean a single column?

Comment: Yes I want my sidebar to be part of the grid (1 colums wide).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper around the entire Bootstrap grid (container>row>cols..) to contain the fixed nav and right sidebar.

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- top nav -->
        <nav>
            ...
        </nav>

        <!-- main -->
        <div class="left" id="main">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1>Bootstrap Grid...</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- sidebar -->
        <div class="right" id="sidebar">
            Fixed right sidebar
        </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/37bttGte6c

Comment: I didn't know if it's good for a good responsive system to build a wrapper around the grid instead to build it in the grid ?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with containing the grid inside an outer wrapper. The important thing is the nested grid uses `container-fluid > row > cols`

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially separate them into their respective `<div>` containers, for example:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default"> Navbar </div>

    <div class="main-content col-md-10"> Main Content </div>

    <div class="right-btn-group col-md-2"> Right buttons </div>
</body>
```

That way the right-side is separated from the main content. Then again I might be misinterpreting the question.

Comment: Yes, but with this method, the width of right side is the witdh of col class, and it's not possible to custom this width right ?

Comment: If you want to do custom formatting of the column width, I would recommend looking at [this link](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/bootstrap-3-tips-and-tricks-you-still-might-not-know), particularly the section "Custom Container Sizes".

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this? You can adjust the width of right container as you wish. No need to edit bootstrap.css or write custom bootstrap classes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    body{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      color: #fff;
    }
    header, footer{
      height: 100px;
    }
    header{
      width: 100%;
      background: #000;
    }
    .content-container{
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
    }
    .left-container{
      width: calc(100% - 90px); /* adjust */
      height: 100%;
    }
    .right-container{
      width: 90px; /* adjust */
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      background: blue;
    }
    .main-content{
      height: 500px;
      background: #ff0000;
    }
    footer{
      width: 100%;
      background: #ed1899;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <header class="nav">nav bar</header>

    <div class="content-container">

      <div class="left-container">
        <div class="main-content">
          //main content
        </div>
        <footer>
          //footer content
        </footer>
      </div>

      <div class="right-container">buttons</div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```